# Need to update table based on results from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update users table based on results from ads table, as follows:

if at least one column in ads is outdated(meaning duration in days from last time ad was edited has finished before today), then update "**changed**" column of the "**users**" table to 1 for the user owning the ad.

Here is my code that gives mysql error:

```sql
UPDATE users SET changed = IF(COUNT (ads.user_id) WHERE    
    (DATEDIFF()/ads.duration)>1 )>0, 1, 0) WHERE ads.user_id = users.id;
```

as you can see I am trying to set users.changed = 1 where ever at least one ad has expired from ads table belonging to this user.
Note that if duration is -1 then this needs not be checked.

Comment: *here is my code that gives mysql error* - what is the error message?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (DATEDIFF()/ads.duration)>1 )>0, 1, 0) WHERE ads.user_id = users.id' at line 1

Comment: What is `ads` it's never been aliased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the `ads` table just after `UPDATE` statement.

You're probably trying to write the query:

```
UPDATE users
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM ads
    WHERE ( DATEDIFF(NOW(), last_edited) / duration > 1 )
    ) ads ON ads.user_id = users.id
SET changed = IF(COUNT (ads.user_id)
;
```

Comment: UPDATE users
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM ads
    WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),last_edited)/duration > 1
    ) ads ON ads.user_id = users.id
SET changed = IF(COUNT(ads.user_id))
;

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 6

Comment: @AnwarSaiah Seems like you're missing a `(`.

Comment: UPDATE users 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT ads.user_id FROM ads WHERE (DATEDIFF(NOW(),ads.last_edited)/ads.duration > 1 )))
            ads ON ads.user_id = users.id SET changed = IF(COUNT(ads.user_id)) ;

Comment: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: UPDATE users 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT ads.user_id FROM ads 
WHERE (DATEDIFF(NOW(),ads.last_edited)/ads.duration > 1 )))ads 
ON users.id = ads.user_id SET users.changed = IF(COUNT(ads.user_id)) ;

Comment: UPDATE users 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT ads.user_id AS uid FROM ads 
WHERE (DATEDIFF(NOW(),ads.last_edited)/ads.duration > 1 )))ads 
ON users.id = ads.user_id SET users.changed = IF(COUNT(ads.user_id)) ;

Comment: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to approach this uses `exists`.  The condition on the time is rather confusing, but I think you want:

```
update users
    set changed = 1
    where exists (select 1
                  from ads a
                  where a.user_id = u.uid and
                        a.last_edited < current_date - ads.duration day
                 );
```

In particular, this assures that each row is updated only once.  When you use a `JOIN` in an update, you can have multiple matches.  That can affect performance and lead to inconsistent results.

Comment: Why do you think `exists` is the better or correct way as opposed to that of inner join, I thought joins were preferred to subqueries?

Comment: @Nae . . . I should have explained that, so I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
UPDATE users 
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT ads.user_id AS uid FROM ads 
    WHERE (DATEDIFF(NOW(),ads.last_edited)/ads.duration) > 1
           ) 
    ads 
ON users.id = uid 
SET users.changed=1
```